# Checking for null more than once when using .Select()

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I deserialize a XML and then read it to a database. I am able to do that just fine, there is just one problem. 
The problem is that I want to be able to check twice for `null` in the XML before deserializing it. Right now I only can check for `null` once.

I have the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Deserilizing FolkbokföringsPost");

var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
    .Select(x => new Person
    {
        PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr != null ? x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr : null,
        SpecialIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering != null ? x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering : null,
        LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn != null ? x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn : null,
        FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn != null ? x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn : null,
        NationalRegistrationCountyCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod : null,
        NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod : null,
        ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null,
        ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
        ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress3 : null,
        NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null,
        NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
        NationalRegistrationPostCode = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null,

        UnregistrationReason = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.AvregistreringsorsakKod : null,
        UnregistrationDate = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.Avregistreringsdatum : null,

        NationalRegistrationCity = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Postort : null,
        BirthCountyCode = x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.FodelselanKod : null,
        BirthParish = x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.Fodelseforsamling : null,
        CitizenshipDate = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap != null ? x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.Medborgarskapsdatum : null,
        GivenNameNumber = x.Personpost.Namn.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering != null ? x.Personpost.Namn.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering : null,
        NationalRegistrationDate = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing != null ? x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.Folkbokforingsdatum : null,


        ProtectedIdentity = x.Sekretessmarkering != null ? x.Sekretessmarkering : null, 

        CitizenshipCode = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod != null ? x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod : null 

    });
```

As you can see on the code above I check for `null` once. For example `ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null`

In that example, it makes sure that`x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress` is not `null` before proceeding. But what if I also want to make sure that `x.Personpost.Adresser` is not `null` before proceeding?

Does anyone know how to check for `null` twice before assigning the value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = (x.Personpost.Adresser!= null 
 && x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress != null) 
 ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress.Utdelningsadress1 
 : null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Null-conditional Operators (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) introduced with [c# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).

i.e.:

```
var a = x?.Personpost?.Adresser?.Utlandsadress;
```

is the short form for:

```
if(x != null && x.Personpost != null && x.Personpost.Adresser != null)
    var a = x.Personpost.Adresser.Utlandsadress;
else
    var a = null;
```

will check first if `x != null`, if not `null` it'll check `Personpost` if it is not `null` and so on. If one is `null`, it will assign `null` to `a`.

---

**Edit:**

if you want to assign a default value to `a` if one is `null`, you can use in addition the `??` operator:

```
var defaultValue = "someValue";
var a = x?.Personpost?.Adresser?.Utlandsadress ?? defaultValue;
```

Comment: Does this require C# 6?

Comment: as Charles Mager said, it was [introduced with c# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: If you have a previous version, you have to use the classic ternary operators as Mukund suggested

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 6 you can use the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn986595.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
x.Personpost?.Adresser?.Utlandsadress
```